# Check Idle Time when running as a Windows Service

Tags: python, winapi, windows-services, python-idle

Using win32api.GetLastInputInfo() is an easy way to determine a USERS's idle time. However when running as a SERVICE this does not apply (always returns 0).

Does anyone know a simple way for a WINDOWS SERVICE to determine last keypress/mouse activity? (or some other effective way to determine idle time)

Comment: Which user? Nowadays on windows, this is not necessarilly only the user sitting in front of the computer (think rdesktop...)

Answer (score 1):

Not in Python, but the approach proposed in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/trackuseridle.aspx looks interesting.

[edit]
The code  it is a standard C DLL, so you should be able to use it with ctypes. The way the C code is written using `SetWindowsHookEx` means you could maybe rewrite it directly Python + pywin32. See stackoverflow.com/questions/6458812 and python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11154 for more on this (the first link mentions kinds of events you can get without writing a DLL, and the other shows a python example).

Comment: From the link it appears that they are intercepting the keypad/mouse low level interrupt. Is it possible to use the above DLL in Python?

Comment: @Ian I added info on this in the answer above. Sorry, don't have a windows machine at hand to try to put up some test code.